# Change of basis Matrix and diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Given a vector space $V,$ the change of coordinates matrix $\left[I_{V}\right]_{\beta}^{\beta}$ from $\beta^{\prime}$ to $\beta$ is always diagonalizable.

What I have tried is in image below.
[image]

Is this correct approach?

Comment: Can you please type your question in MathJax? That is the common procedure on this website. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is it about your attempt that you are unsure about? Knowing this will better help us help you.